HTTP 400 Error when uploading Kubeflow Pipeline to Artifact Registry [google cloud platform]
Problem Statement
I'm encountering a 400 (Bad Request) error when attempting to upload a Kubeflow pipeline to Google Artifact Registry.
Environment Setup
kfp==2.10.1
kfp-pipeline-spec==0.5.0

Configuration
Repository Format: Kubeflow Pipeline
IAM: artifactregistry.writer role  and artifactregistry.admin roleconfigured
Region: europe-west1
Reproducible Code Example
1. Initial Setup
(a repo need to be created first in artifact registry in kfp format)
from kfp import dsl, compiler
from kfp.registry import RegistryClient

ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_URL = "https://europe-west1-kfp.pkg.dev/my_project/ml-pipeline"
PIPELINE_OUTPUT_PATH = "pipeline.yml"

2. Pipeline Definition
@dsl.pipeline(
name="example_pipeline",
description="Example pipeline to demonstrate upload to Artifact Registry"
)
def my_pipeline():
\# Pipeline definition here
pass

3. Compilation and Upload
python
Compilation
pipeline_func=my_pipeline,
package_path=PIPELINE_OUTPUT_PATH
)

Upload
client = RegistryClient(host=ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_URL)
client.upload_pipeline(file_name=PIPELINE_OUTPUT_PATH)

Error Message
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://europe-west1-kfp.pkg.dev/my_project/ml-pipeline

Specific Questions

Are there any missing steps in the repository configuration?
How can I better debug this HTTP 400 error?

Troubleshooting Steps Taken

✅ Verified pipeline.yml file generation

File generates without errors
YAML structure appears valid
No compilation errors reported


✅ Checked IAM permissions

Confirmed artifactregistry.writer role
User account has necessary access
Service account permissions verified


✅ Validated repository URL

URL format matches documentation
Repository exists and is accessible
Region configuration is correct



End Goal
Automate the upload of pipeline updates to Artifact Registry for automatic synchronization with Vertex AI.
Additional Context
I'm using the @pipeline decorator (versus @dsl.pipeline seen in some examples)
The Artifact Registry repository is configured in Kubeflow Pipeline format
All required IAM permissions are in place
The YAML file generation completes successfully
thanks you !

Unfamiliar with KFP but familiar with Artifact Registry. The URL appears correct (I assume you have a Project my_project containing a KFP repository in europe-west1?). One debugging step you could try is to upload your artifact using a tool like curl, this will eliminate your Python code from the configuration. See example curl request. You'll need to impersonate the service account

My immediate reaction is that you're not (evidently) authenticating the request but you're also not receiving a 403. It's possible that the error is being obfuscated. I noticed that there is an auth property on kfp.registry.RegistryClient which isn't being set (unless it's leveraging ADC?)

I've configured my authentication using ADC by running gcloud auth application-default login and 
